# How to solve "stale" issue on istio proxy?

Tags: istio

I've applied some updates of istio Policy and DestionationRule (basically istio configuration) around my services, exposed by the Ingress Gateway. And somehow it doesn't reflect my configuration policy.

After looking at the `istioctl proxy-status` command, I see many istio's proxies being staled.

```
PROXY                                                             CDS        LDS        EDS               RDS          PILOT                            VERSION
data-devops-istio-ingressgateway-66bddd766d-75gjz.data-devops     SYNCED     SYNCED     SYNCED (100%)     STALE        istio-pilot-6cd95f9cc4-8pcw4     1.0.0
data-devops-istio-ingressgateway-66bddd766d-fjkcr.data-devops     SYNCED     SYNCED     SYNCED (100%)     STALE        istio-pilot-6cd95f9cc4-8pcw4     1.0.0
istio-egressgateway-868bb74854-lzhqt.istio-system                 SYNCED     SYNCED     SYNCED (100%)     NOT SENT     istio-pilot-6cd95f9cc4-8pcw4     1.0.0
istio-egressgateway-868bb74854-p25p2.istio-system                 SYNCED     SYNCED     SYNCED (100%)     NOT SENT     istio-pilot-6cd95f9cc4-8pcw4     1.0.0
istio-ingressgateway-f86f68645-887dd.istio-system                 SYNCED     STALE      SYNCED (100%)     SYNCED       istio-pilot-6cd95f9cc4-8pcw4     1.0.0
istio-ingressgateway-f86f68645-bnrvt.istio-system                 SYNCED     STALE      SYNCED (100%)     SYNCED       istio-pilot-6cd95f9cc4-8pcw4     1.0.0
istio-ingressgateway-f86f68645-g6s9g.istio-system                 SYNCED     STALE      SYNCED (100%)     SYNCED       istio-pilot-6cd95f9cc4-8pcw4     1.0.0
istio-ingressgateway-f86f68645-gf4nq.istio-system                 SYNCED     STALE      SYNCED (100%)     SYNCED       istio-pilot-6cd95f9cc4-8pcw4     1.0.0
istio-ingressgateway-f86f68645-xzfth.istio-system                 SYNCED     STALE      SYNCED (100%)     STALE        istio-pilot-6cd95f9cc4-8pcw4     1.0.0
java-maven-app-canary-5b9f57b475-r9lfc.data-devops                SYNCED     SYNCED     SYNCED (100%)     SYNCED       istio-pilot-6cd95f9cc4-8pcw4     1.0.0
java-maven-app-stable-56b9c47c9-nhmhd.data-devops                 SYNCED     SYNCED     SYNCED (100%)     SYNCED       istio-pilot-6cd95f9cc4-8pcw4     1.0.0
```

Is there any solution to solve the stale issue? Also, what does `CDS`, `LDS`, `EDS`, and `RDS` mean?

Comment: Could you provide more information about the content of the Policy and DestinationRule updates?

Answer (score 0):

- CDS - Cluster Discovery Service
- LDS - Listener Discovery Service
- EDS - Endpoint Discovery Service
- RDS - Route Discovery Service

They all are explained well in the [Envoy doc](https://github.com/envoyproxy/data-plane-api/blob/master/XDS_PROTOCOL.md).

Coming back to your problem I would look at both Pilot and Istio Proxy logs to see whats happening. Its also worth increasing the Pilot replicas if you havent to see if there is any improvement. I have 2 or 3 Pilot pods running depending on the CPU utilisation. Hope this helps.